# CHOWN running process in LINUX (EC2)

Tags: linux, tomcat, permissions, chown

I have two users A and B in EC2 Linux Instance. A is in Group X, B is in Group Y. I start tomcat instance as User A. I own the tomcat instance directory as "chown -R A:Y tomcat/"

I started the tomcat as A User. How do I stop the tomcat as User B or restart as User B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since user B belongs to group Y, it is necessary to have execute permission of group Y on tomcat folder/bin/catalina.sh file. Please check if you have it. If not, you have to give it using chmod x5x on tomcat folder/bin/catalina.sh

Comment: Then its alright. You have to just call ./catalina.sh stop command inside bin folder of tomcat directory with user B. It should be able to stop your service.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ajay. I have the execute permission to the catalina.sh in bin folder. 

drwxr-xr-x  2 A Y  4096 Aug 29 07:14 bin

-rwxr-xr-x  1 A Y  17708 Nov 28  2011 catalina.sh

As A User the status of tomcat is as follows

[A] service tomcat status
java (pid 29518) is running...

service tomcat restart
Stopping test-tomcat:                                      [FAILED]
Starting test-tomcat:                                      [FAILED]

Because, the process was not able to be killed by User B as it is owned by User A.

Comment: Sorry for misinterpretation, typically this is not possible in linux, because user who has started the service can only stop it(root user can do it too). workaround to your problem is user B can execute a script in which you should first su to user A then call catalina.sh stop command. user A will only be able to stop it. Sorry again for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo` to set up rules that allow user B to run certain things (specifically the stop and start scripts) as user A (possibly without supplying a password, even, if that is desired and considered secure enough).

Comment: But Amazon EC2 allows only ec2-user with SUDO access. So users or groups created is not allowed for sudo!!! setting up rules on the script is working and if I start as A user and stop as A User it is working.... if no tomcat is running, i can start as B User without harm....